# Grabbing individual elements in MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, database, breadcrumbs

I'm attempting to add Breadcrumbs to my website using a MySQL table, and I'm having difficulty at the moment.

I have a table named 'includes' created that stores information about the category, page, subpage, the title, and the ref (url) of the page. Category, Page, and Subpage are all php parameters passed from the page the user is on

My table is laid out like this:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| ID |  Category  |  Page   |  Subpage  |  Title           | Ref |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 0  |            |         |           | Home             | ... |
| 1  | Software   |         |           | Software         | ... |
| 2  | Software   | Desktop |           | Desktop Software | ... |
| 3  | Software   | Mobile  |           | Mobile Software  | ... |
| 4  | Software   | Desktop | Blah      | Blah Blah        | ... |
| ...
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

What I'm trying to do is make a query that will return only the required steps back to home for the breadcrumbs.

In other words, if the user is on "example.com/software/desktop/blah", the query will return rows 0,1,2, and 4. Or if I was on /software/mobile, it would only return rows 0,1, and 3.

My current attempts have been things like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `includes` WHERE
`category` IS NULL     AND `page` IS NULL AND `subpage` IS NULL OR
`category`='$category' AND `page` IS NULL AND `subpage` IS NULL OR
`category`='$category' AND `page`='$page' AND `subpage` IS NULL OR
`category`='$category' AND `page`='$page' AND `subpage`='$subpage'
```

Which not only don't work, but also seem more complex than it should have to be.

I'm probably overcomplicating this, or possibly just doing an entirely wrong method, which is why I've turned here.

Does anyone have a possible solution to this? Should I be looking at a more complex query? (admittedly, SQL is not my forte) Or should I be looking at a new SQL table, or possibly an entirely different method?

Comment: your idea of organizing this table is wrong. you need to make a hierarchical table, using upper level entry id as a parent id of the subordinate entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a hierarchical structure. The data is set up with parent-child relationships. There is a good description on how to work with hierarchical data here: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: I've started reading this, but will finish it in the morning when I think I can retain/understand it >_< Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `self relation` table like this

```
id | parent_it | title | Ref 

1  | 0         | Home  | ... 
2  | 1         | Software  | ... 
3  | 2         | Desktop  | ... 
4  | 2         | Mobile  | ... 
5  | 3         | Blah  | ...
```

So your query should get the last element 
SELECT * FROM `includes` WHERE
`tilte` = 'Blah'

And then get the parent ID title and so on , like this the table structure will be better from my point of view & experience

**OR**

Generate your query based on the values you get , with simple loop count the arguments and based on that generate the query string then execute it

I hope this can help :)

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense.
I'm still new to MySQL, so I hadn't even thought of it that way; I will try to implement this.

Is there any way to make a single query that can return all the parent IDs, or would this be a series of queries?